# Why does including FastMM cause an EInvalidTypecast error?

Tags: delphi, fastmm

This is with Delphi XE2 and FastMM 4.99, and a 32-bit program on a Win7-64 machine.

I was trying to use FastMM to check a smallish program I've been working on. The program includes a data module that is on the project's auto-created forms list. The data module contains only a TADOConnection object.

When I enable FullDebugMode in FastMM, I get an invalid typecast error when exiting the program. The culprit seems to be in freeing the datamodule (the error occurs in `TADOConnection.GetADODataSet`). Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: Clearly it's happening because the code attempts a typecast that is invalid. Without being able to see the code it's pretty hard to be more specific. If you want help, provide adequate details.

Comment: Install MadExcept and at least you'll find out WHERE the error is happening.

Comment: Adding madExcept to your app is ALWAYS a good idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was just something that was exposed by FastMM, not caused by it.

Specifically, I'd subclassed `TADOQuery` for use with the data module. I remembered to write a destructor override for the class, but failed to call the inherited dtor. Probably this was causing the `TADOConnection` to do something undefined.

Comment: Didn't that give you a COMPILER WARNING? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it's hard to say exactly, but when you're having problems when freeing something, it's usually because it's trying to free something that's already been freed.  Try placing a few breakpoints to see if any of the classes involved are getting freed before you see this error.  If so, that should help you track it down.